# Django question: Having a problem with saving

Tags: django, date, button, view, save

Hello I have  an edit item form. From this view, look at `item.current_item_status_date`.

```
def edit_item(request, client_id = 0, item_id = 0):
    client = None
    item = None
    status = None
    contact = None
    status_id = request.POST.get('status_id', None)
    contact_id = request.POST.get('contact_id', None)
    save_item = request.POST.get('save_item', None)
    save_status = request.POST.get('save_status', None)

    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        item = models.StorageItem.objects.get(pk = item_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    try:
        status = models.Status.objects.get(pk = status_id)
        contact = models.Contact.objects.get(pk = contact_id)
    except:
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ItemForm(request.POST, instance = item)
        if form.is_valid() and save_item is not None:
            item.current_item_status_date = date.today()
            item.save()
            form.save(True)
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item {0} has been updated successfully.".format(item.tiptop_id))
            return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")

        if status is not None and contact is not None and save_status is not None:
            current_status = models.ItemStatusHistory(item = item, contact = contact, status = status,
                                                    user = request.user)
            current_status.save()
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item status has been updated successfully.")
    else:
        form = forms.ItemForm(instance = item)
    title = str(client) + ' : Edit Item'
    status_list = models.Status.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('edit_item.html', {'form':form, 'title':title, 'status_list':status_list, 'item':item}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

current_item_status_date saves todays date when the form is submitted. However, there is a small problem. In my form, I only want it to save when the button called **new status** 
is selected. Right now what my edit item form is doing is it's saving when the **Save** button is selected. I want my form to save this date only when **new status** is selected - not  **Save**.

Here is what I have in my edit order template.

```
<td><input type="submit" name="save_status" value="new status"></td>
<input type="submit" name="save_item" value="Save" onclick="validate_item(this.form)">
```

**Edit:**: I have done these changes.

```
#code

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ItemForm(request.POST, instance = item)
    if form.is_valid() and save_item is not None:
        form.save(True)
        request.user.message_set.create(message = "Item {0} has been updated successfully.".format(item.tiptop_id))
        return HttpResponse("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.location = window.opener.location; window.close();</script>")
    if request.POST.get('save_status'):
        item.current_item_status_date = date.today()
        item.save()
#code
```

Now, by doing this, the current item status date does get saved. But only if I close the form (It is a form that opens a new window). It does not get saved when I select status date and then click save. I think it is not getting saved properly into the the current_item_status_date field, rather than the database. I can tell it is not working when I click on save status, the field current_item_status does not update. It only updates when I close the form and open it up again. The only way it will work is if the form reloads getting information from the database.

This is what I am looking for:

- Clicking on status date should save the date.
- Clicking on status date and then clicking on save should save the date.
- Just clicking on save should not save the status date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `current_item_status_date` field from `form = forms.ItemForm` seems to have worked. This way it can get saved properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking specifically for save_item. Change it to save_status and you should be fine if I understand your question.

```
 if form.is_valid() and save_status is not None:
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it affects `current_status`. doesn't save that part. If I make this change.

Comment: then move it above your HttpResponse block.